# Loop over a list of dicts whose key/value pairs are not standardized

Tags: python

I have a large list of dicts that don't have a specific pattern for its key/value pairs. I need to extract specific values, such as username, hostname, host_ip, any any other pertinent values. Apart from not having a particular standard, sometimes the dict doesn't have the value at all. For instance, the username might be found in one dict, but not in the other.

Here is a sample of the list:

```
logs = [{
        '_index': '.siem-signals-default-000015', 
        '_type': '_doc', 
        '_id': '456', 
        '_score': None, 
        '_source': {
            '@timestamp': '2023-03-22T14:05:53.855Z', 
            'ecs': {'version': '1.10.0'}, 
            'host': {
                'id': '456', 
                'name': 'SRV2', 
                'ip': ['172.30.5.115', 'fe80::5efe:ac1e:573'], 
                'mac': ['00:00:00:00:00:00:00',  
                'architecture': 'x86_64', 
                'os': {'build': '14393.5717', 'type': 'windows'}
                }, 
                'log': {'level': 'warning'}, 
                'message': 'Some message', 
                'file': {
                    'directory': 'C:', 
                    'extension': 'psm1', 
                    'path': 'C:', 
                    'name': 'Heartbeat.psm1'
                    }, 
                'agent': {
                    'name': 'SRV2', 
                    'type': 'winlogbeat', 
                    'version': '7.14.1', 
                    'hostname': 'SRV2', 
                    'ephemeral_id': '456a', 
                    'id': '4567'
                    }, 
                'winlog': {
                    'user': {'name': 'SYSTEM', 'type': 'User', 'identifier': 'S-1-5-18', 'domain': 'NT AUTHORITY'}, 
                    'event_id': '4104', 
                    'opcode': 'On create calls', 
                    'provider_name': 'Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell', 
                    'channel': 'Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational', 
                    }, 
                    }}, 

    {
        '_index': '.siem-signals-default-000015', 
        '_type': '_doc', 
        '_id': '123', 
        '_score': None, 
        '_source': {
            '@timestamp': '2023-03-22T14:05:53.854Z', 
            'winlog': {
                'user': {'identifier': 'S-1-5-18', 'domain': 'NT AUTHORITY', 'name': 'SYSTEM', 'type': 'User'}, 
                'task': 'Execute a Remote Command', 
                'computer_name': 'SRV1', 
                'provider_name': 'Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell', 
                }, 
            'event': {
                'provider': 'Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell', 
                'action': 'Execute a Remote Command', 
                'created': '2023-03-22T14:02:36.498Z', 
                }, 
            'log': {'level': 'warning'}, 
            'powershell': {
                'sequence': 1, 
                'total': 1, 
                'file': {
                    'script_block_id': '123', 
                    'script_block_text': "Some script"
                    }
                                }, 
            'ecs': {'version': '1.10.0'}, 
            'message': "Some message", 
            'host': {
                'mac': ['00:00:00:00:00:00:00', '00:00:00:00:00:00:00'], 
                'hostname': 'SRV1', 
                'architecture': 'x86_64', 
                'os': {
                    'build': '14393.5717', 
                    'type': 'windows', 
                    }, 
                'id': '456', 
                'ip': ['172.30.5.115', 'fe80::5efe:ac1e:573']
                    }, 
            'user': {'id': 'S-1-5-18'}, 
                    }, 
        'sort': [1679493953854]
    }]
```

In this sample list, you see that there is a hostname in both dictionaries, but they are located under different key/value pairs, and even at different levels of the dict. In the first dict, you can find it under `['_source']['host']['name']`, but the other is found under `['_source']['host']['hostname']`.

```
def printlogs(logs):
    for items in logs:
        for k, v in items.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                pritlogs(v)
            else:
                print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
printlogs(logs)
```

I tried several things but none successful so far. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Technically both records have that entry `['_source]['host']['hostname']` is that a factor here?

Comment: Could you provide an example of which values from the example data you want to print out?

Comment: @JonSG Hey, yeah, that is one example, Eve though 'hostname' exists, it is found in different places -- one is under ['_source]['host']['hostname'] and the other under ['_source]['agent']['hostname']. I updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: So, you want the value of a given key no matter where that key falls in the tree?  Is that right?  For example, you want the value of the first/last key "hostname" no matter where that key exists in these trees, the first being `['_source]['host']['hostname']` the second being `['_source]['agent']['hostname']` right?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Overall, I need username, hostname, user_ip, host_ip, and maybe other values. But the thing is that these are all over the place in the actual logs, so it makes it hard to provide a small and concise example. I guess in this sample, you could go by hostname.

Comment: Typo: `pritlogs(v)` should be `printlogs(v)`

Comment: Your code never looks for the key `hostname` in the dictionary. It just recurses and prints everything that isn't a dictionary.

Comment: Why do you say they're at different levels? They're both nested 3 levels deep, inside either `host` or `agent` keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the key and want the "first" value in each nested dictionary that matches that key, then you can try this.

```py
def find_value_for_key(key, data):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for item in data:
            result = find_value_for_key(key, item)
            if result:
                return result

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        if key in data:
            return data[key]
        for value in data.values():
            result = find_value_for_key(key, value)
            if result:
                return result
        
for log in logs:
    print(find_value_for_key("hostname", log))
```

That should give you:

```
SRV2
SRV1
```

If you know your data does not contain lists of dictionaries, you can probably just do:

```py
def find_value_for_key(key, data):
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        return None
    
    if key in data:
        return data[key]

    for value in data.values():
        if result := find_value_for_key(key, value):
            return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
for d in logs:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if 'host' in v:
            print('Host: %s' %v['host'])
        if 'user' in v: 
            print('User: %s' %v['user'])
```

This code inspects every item of the list, and checks whether the item is a dict containing the keys "host" and "user". If these conditions are met, the corresponding values are printed.

The variable names in the above code mean "dict", "key", and "value".

---

You can also do it this way:

```
for d in logs:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if 'host' in v:
                print('Host: %s' %v['host'])
            if 'user' in v: 
                print('User: %s' %v['user'])
```

Which version of the code is more efficient? That's an interesting question. A function call can add overhead and it's not clear whether the `isinstance` function call is needed.

---

If you know in advance that the "host" and "user" keys are always stored in a `d["_source"]` subdictionary, then you can do this.

```
for d in logs:
    if "_source" in d:
        if "user" in d["_source"]:
            print("User: %s" %d["_source"]["user"])
        if "host" in d["_source"]:
            print("Host: %s" %d["_source"]["host"])
```

---

These are a few approaches to finding the "host" and "user" values. I think what's best here is to find the approach that is most efficient for your particular data structure.

Comment: How will this get the `['_source']['host']['hostname']` and `['_source']['agent']['hostname']` values that are nested more deeply?

Comment: The key '_source' will be read by the for loop, and as soon as it is, the code will check for the keys 'host' and 'user'.

Comment: But the question is about `host` and `agent`. And they want to get the `hostname` values, not the whole dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the dictionary has `host` or `agent` keys, then get the nested `hostname` within it.

```
for item in logs:
    if 'host' in item['source']:
        print(item['source']['host']['hostname'])
    elif 'agent' in item['source']:
        print(item['source']['agent']['hostname'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be:

```
    printlogs(v)
```

Instead of "pritlogs(v)"
I think there's a typo...